# Regex with SpEl usage

Tags: regex, spring, spring-integration, spring-el

How to use regex with SpEL?

Would like to append system properties along with SpEL and regex .

expected output : devInmessagebase/devInmessagetest/devInmessagesample

dev :'env' variable

Inmessage : from properties file(in.topic.mesge)

asterisk(*) : base/test/sample(anything as suffix)

Tried as below and many other ways but not working.any suggestion?

```
 <int-kafka:consumer-configuration group-id="default3" value-decoder="kafkaSpecificDecoder" 
            key-decoder="kafkaReflectionDecoder" max-messages="10"> 
            <int-kafka:topic-filter pattern="${systemProperties['env'] + in.topic.mesge.'*'}" streams="4" exclude="false" /> </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for the `pattern` attribute is:

```
pattern="#{systemProperties['env'] + '${in.topic.mesge}' + '.*'}"
```

Comment: Hi @Garry Russell,
 
Thanks for the reply.getting below error.
 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#43c0b942': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.TopicFilterConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: dev${in.topic.mesge}.* is an invalid regex.

Comment: You need a `<context:property-placeholder/> ` to add a configurer to resolve the placeholder. It needs to point to your properties file.

Comment: i am having the properties file in place.if i mention only <int-kafka:topic id="${in.topic.mesge}".it resolve to the expected value from the prop file.

Comment: I think you must be mistaken. Turn on debug logging for org.springframework and watch the property resolution.

Comment: I changed the [test case here](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-kafka/commit/45f32be7351ba1665974d43e36e3e0b8f5a87f4e) and it worked fine for me when running with `-Dfoo=bar`.

Comment: Hi @Gary,

It is working fine.
My bad,sorry for the confusion created.

Issue: I have multiple spring config file in classpath and  one of the file has <context:property-placeholder/> was defined.While running the junit test ,it seems was not picking the prop details from that file.so put it in the specific config file and working.

Many thanks.