# Kafka channel routing using SpEL and regex

Tags: regex, spring, spring-integration, spring-el

Would like to route to the channel based on the SpEL regex  combination(so that multiple message from different topic/payload can be routed to same channel).
Tried as above and other combination using different router types available.Not working.

```
<int:recipient-list-router  input-channel="receiveMessageChannel">
 <int:recipient channel="in_channel" selector-expression="headers['topic']  matches  #{systemProperties['env'] + '${in.msge.topic}' + '.*'}"/>
 <int:recipient channel="email_channel" selector-expression="headers['topic']  matches #{systemProperties['env'] + '${email.msge.topic}' + '.*'}"/>
 </int:recipient-list-router>
```

getting below error:

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1049E:(pos 37): Unexpected data after '.': 'star(*)'

headers['topic'] = mesge.getPayload().setHeaders("topic","testTopic");

Can anyone provide some suggestion.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matches argument must be a `String`. Here's the correct syntax...

```
selector-expression="headers['topic']  matches '#{systemProperties[env]}${in.msge.topic}.*'"
```

Note that it won't work with dotted `systemProperties`. You need to add quotes for that...

```
selector-expression="headers['topic']  matches '#{systemProperties[&quot;env.foo&quot;]}${in.msge.topic}.*'"/>
```

The reason this is a little different to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132019/regex-with-spel-usage/33132867#33132867) is because, in that case, the SpEL expression evaluates to a value that is used as a simple `String` during context initialization.

In this case, we need to evaluate to a `String` that's used at runtime as part of another SpEL expression - hence the whole thing needs to be surrounded by `'...'`.

Comment: Hi @Gary
Thanks for the reply and the explanation.It is working fine.